# Answering closed questions

Tags: discussion

There was a question just posted that was closed (rightly so) due to being trivia and not relevant to the understanding of the movie.  I know the answer to this question and could drop it into a comment on the closed question.  Is that bad form or okay?

Answer (score 3):

While it's something that you **can** do, I really can't encourage this behavior.  The reason being is that, if people know that they'll still get an answer, they'll ask an off-topic question ***on purpose*** to still get their answer.

I think the best course of action is to convince these users to enter chat so that you can give them the answer to thier off-topic question there.